# One-Way Binding works, Two-Way Binding doesn't

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, data-binding

In my Silverlight prjoect I am creating a simple two-way binding in code:

This is the property I want to bind to:

```
public class Selection : ViewModelBase {

    private string selectedModel;

    public string SelectedModel {
        get { return selectedModel; }
        set {
            selectedModel = value;
            FirePropertyChanged("SelectedModel");
        }
    }
}
```

My binding target is the text property of a rich text box.

My binding code is the following:

```
Selection s = getSelectionObject();

Binding modelBinding = new Binding("SelectedModel");
modelBinding.Source = s.SelectedModel;
selectorContent.usc_ModelSelector.SetBinding(GSelector.TextProperty, modelBinding);
```

That works fine! Every time the SelectedModel property of the Selection object changes, the rich text box is getting notified and updated accordingly. But it's only bound one-way and I need it bound two-way. So i have tried to change the binding mode by altering the above code:

```
Binding modelBinding = new Binding("SelectedModel");
modelBinding.Path = new PropertyPath(s.SelectedModel);
modelBinding.Source = s.SelectedModel;
modelBinding.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
selectorContent.usc_ModelSelector.SetBinding(GSelector.TextProperty, modelBinding);
```

But that doesn't work. It compiles but the whole binding now seems to be without effect. Not only that I can't trigger a change in the ViewModel (in the Selection class in the SelectedModel property - which should be the effect when two-way binding would work correctly) when changing the text of the RichTextBox, I even can't see the one-way binding wokring any more which worked with the above code!

It seems that the line

```
modelBinding.Path = new PropertyPath(s.SelectedModel);
```

is the source of the problem because when I set s.SelectedModel as the bindings Path property then the Path property of the modelBinding object seems to have the correct value (which revealed a look inside the object during runtine while debugging - it is a string value) but I can't see any change in the rich text box.

Restoring the code to the one-way binding version immediately makes the rich text box work again as it should.

Can anyone help ? I already spent several hours in this and i really have to catch a customer's deadline .. So any help would be highly appreciated :) Many thanks in advance ...

Comment: Why did you add that property path line whe all you want to do is change the mode to two way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
new Binding("SelectedModel");
```

Creates a new binding with the path `"SelectedModel"`. Then you go on to overwrite the correct path with this line:

```
modelBinding.Path = new PropertyPath(s.SelectedModel);
```

Which is not going to work; The [constructor reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms587925.aspx) states:

> A property path that either describes a path to a common language runtime (CLR) property, or a single dependency property.

So either use a string or a reference to a DP.

Anyway, i do not think that you need that line at all because you already set the path correctly in the binding constructor.

**Edit:** Your source is wrong!

The source should be the object containing the property, here that is `s`.

```
Binding modelBinding = new Binding("SelectedModel");
modelBinding.Source = s;
modelBinding.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay; // This might be optional depending on the default mode of the target property
```

Comment: Hi and thank your for your answer. I can indeed remove the "SelectedModel" parameter in Binding("SelectdModel") but i changes nothing to my situation i see no difference in having it than not having it. And the line with the explicit Path property is needed because if i remove it the compiler says: "A two-way binding needs a Path." Any further ideas, please ? :)

Comment: @Marc: No no no, you should leave the Binding construction *as it is*, just remove the line where you overwrite the path, you have to have one of them (but only the contructor is correct so leave that).

Comment: it's interesting that when i set the Path via the binding constructor the Path property of the binding object gets initialized but its "Path" property remains null. On the other hand when I set the Path of the binding explicitly like in modelBindinf.Path = ... than the Path property gets initialized AND the paths' Path property (a bit confusing i know) now has the string value inside which is the value i want to band to.

Comment: @Marc: Some .NET classes behave differently when created by the parser or internal machanisms, one example would be templates. Anyway, `new Binding("SelectedModel")` should be equivalent to `new Binding() { Path = new PropertyPath("SelectedModel") }`

Comment: OK I see you. But would you say would be the correct Path for my binding-issue ? I want to bind to the SelectedModel property of my Selection class. So far i thought it is Path="SelectedModel" ? Is that correct ?

Comment: @Marc: Yes, that should be correct, if the source is the `Selection` instance that is. You say that the one-way binding worked just fine, the only thing you should need to do is set the binding mode to `TwoWay` as the binding itself demonstrably works.

Comment: H.B., as i said the one-way works quite fine. my trouble starts as soon as i try to change to two-way binding ...

Comment: should i modify the SelectedRange property somehow, maybe make a dependency property out of it ??

Comment: @Marc: So you are binding to a different property? If it isn't a dependency property of course that would not work, even with a one-way binding, the target needs to be a dependency property.

Comment: H.B., I just found out, that my one-way binding works, as soon as i fill the Path property of the binding object (i.e. rangeBinding in my above code) with some path that makes the Path property of the Path property (i know confusing again) become null. that is when the modelBinding.Path.Path = null holds then my one-way bionding works. Do you have any explanation for that ?

Comment: i mistyped the name of the property i want to two-way bind. of course it is SelectedModel and NOT SelectedRange although it would have the same structure and is located in the same class (Selection).

Comment: @Marc: I completely overlooked something, your comment pointed me to it. If the path is null you bind directly to the source and the source was set to SelectedModel (which *you do not want*), bindings directly to the source can never be two-way, see my edit to the answer.

Comment: H.B., It is working !! Your comment on changing the Source was absolutely the right one! Please take my deepest Thanks! Now i can try to continue with my work (until my head bounces into my keyboard, because here we have 2 am local time and i am on it since 9 am!) but anyway, again THANK YOU VERY MUCH !! :)

Comment: @Marc: You're welcome! (Actually i am embarrassed to not have noticed the problem so long). 2am over here too by the way :)